# Very Confusing Float64MultiArray Error

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get `rospy.exceptions.ROSSerializationException: field data[] must be float type` in terminal
When I rostopic echo a topic recieving `Float64MultiArray` message. This is a snippet of my python code:

```
M = Float64MultiArray()
Tab=np.zeros((11521,10))
Values in Tab are manipulated,some are int, some are float.
M.data=(Tab.astype(float)).tolist()
pub.publish(M)
```

I don't get it, M.data is of type `float`. is Tab too big?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410541/very-confusing-float64multiarray-error/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-12-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlessioParmeggiani](https://answers.ros.org/users/94489/alessioparmeggiani/) on 2022-12-15**:
Did you try creating the array by setting explicitly the type: `Tab=np.zeros((11521,10),dtype=np.float64)`?

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-12-15**:
@AlessioParmeggiani This still gives the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `.tolist()` call is not doing what you think it is. If you want to flatten a 2d `np.ndarray` to a 1d list, use the `ravel()` method of ndarray.

```
M.data = Tab.astype(float).ravel()
```

For a good discussion, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021939/numpy-reshaping-an-array-to-1-d

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-12-18**:
@Mike Scheutzow This flattens all elements to a list like `[x y z d]`. I want to publish this `[ [x y],[z d] ]`. Maybe it's not possible?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-12-18**:
You can easily adapt it in a few lines though, why is it a problem? Flatten it to 1D list, then create a 2D list with `np.reshape`

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-12-18**:
@ljaniec "facepalm" thanks! I'll try that

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-12-19**:
*I want to publish this [ [x y],[z d] ]*

No, that is not possible with this message. From the message definition: data must be a 1d array of float64.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-12-19**:
Good note, the ROS message definition matters here. This transformation should be in the subscriber callback if wanted.